# How To Populate Children In MongoDB Schema Using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 documents a "User Document" and a "UserToken Document". This should be like a 1-to-Many relationship.

**user.model.js**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({


    username: {

        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true

    },
    email: {

        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },

    password: {

        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },

    tokens: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'UserToken'
    }],


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**usertoken.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserTokenSchema = new Schema({

    type: {
        type: String
    },

    token: {
        type: String
    },

    expiry: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },

    user: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]


});


module.exports = mongoose.model('UserToken', UserTokenSchema);
```

**user.controller**

```
var user = new User({

        username: input.username,
        email: input.email,
        password: input.password,
        active: false

});


user.save(function(err) {

        var userToken = new UserToken({

            type: 'new',
            token: token,
            expiry: null,
            user: user._id



        userToken.save(function(err) {

        })
})
```

When i display a user, it should populate/retrieve all the tokens associated with that user. At the moment its not doing this.

**Query**

```
User.find({})
    .populate('tokens') 
    .exec(function(err, users) {

    if(err) return res.json({success: 'false', errors: err});

    return res.json(users);

});
```

**Data**

```
[
   {
    username: "TestUser",
    email: "TestEmail@hotmail.com",
    password: "$2a$10$I4wJ.e3eVK7EMcfdf46x0e5kYnSTzHPTcBmzXIctduM./pZEiGbPG",
    _id: "56ab4bbfa8f3e11813803566",
    __v: 0,
    tokens: [ ],
    active: false
    }
]
```

It is however retrieving the associated user when i display the token.

**Query**

```
UserToken.find({})
         .populate('user')
         .exec(function(err, tokens) {

    if(err) return res.json({success: 'false', errors: err});

    return res.json(tokens);


});
```

**Data**

```
 [


  {
    type: "new",
    token: "16c72da8-78a7-4ee1-9b03-f5e490d7e010",
    _id: "56ab4bbfa8f3e11813803567",
    __v: 0,
    user: [
    {
    username: "TestUser",
    email: "TestEmail@hotmail.com",
    password: "$2a$10$I4wJ.e3eVK7EMcfdf46x0e5kYnSTzHPTcBmzXIctduM./pZEiGbPG",
    _id: "56ab4bbfa8f3e11813803566",
    __v: 0,
    tokens: [ ],
    active: false
    }
    ],
    expiry: null
    }
]
```

How can i retrieve the user with all associated tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This should be like a 1-to-Many relationship.

Feeling that in your solution you're modeling a **N** to **N** relationship:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    tokens: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'UserToken'
    }]
...


var UserTokenSchema = new Schema({
    user: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
...
```

Apart, how are you inserting data in your db? Remember there will be no framework understanding the *relationship* and you must do it manually (updating the refs each time you create a new document) For example

```
var u1 = {  ...  }
Users.create(u1, function(err, user) {
  UserTokens.findAndUpdate(userTokenId, {user: user._id}, function(err, uToken){
     // now userToken has the reference to your new user (u1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Ive updated my original question to show u how im creating the user and the user token in my user controller. Could you show me the correct way to do a 1-N relationship in the schema aswell.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, i must create the token first then set the token id inside of a user.tokens array.

Comment: But what if something goes wrong during the user creation like sending an email fails. If its linear i cn't revert back to when the user was not created without manually deleting everything i created.

Comment: @KHAN can I suggest you to make "userToken" an embedded document of "user" - I don't know the logic of your app, but still sounds to be a good choice :)

Comment: Can you find an embedded document by a different field such as the token instead of the _id? From what i saw in the docs you can't thats why i opted for a separate document.

Comment: Try with {"tokens.token": "my-token"}